Table content goes off page
As per the following image, the document name (and its content) get cut by the page:

This does not happen when document name (and its content) are small enough:

How can I fix?
This is the reproducible .text file, without the .png image:
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  a4paper,
  top=1.5cm,
  bottom=1.5cm,
  left=1cm,
  right=1cm
}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[10pt]{moresize}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{table}
    \caption{(*) If applicable}
    \vspace{1mm} % Adjust the height of the space between caption and tabular
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.1\paperwidth}p{0.1\paperwidth}|p{0.1\paperwidth}p{0.1\paperwidth}|p{0.1\paperwidth}|p{0.1\paperwidth}p{0.12\paperwidth}|}
\hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{3}{*}{ \fbox{ \begin{minipage}{3cm} \ssmall DOC TYPE \end{minipage} } }} & \small Preparation & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \small DD/MM/YYYY } & \small DOC AUTHOR &  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ \begin{minipage}{3cm} \ssmall DOCUMENT NAME \end{minipage} }    \\ \cline{2-5}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                  & \small Revision (*) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \small DD/MM/YYYY } & \small REVIEWER &  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ Nesque porro quisquam est non abunant in abla latinum est nomen } \\ \cline{2-7} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                  & \small Approval (*) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \small DD/MM/YYYY } & \small APPROVER &  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ \begin{minipage}{3cm} \ssmall CDRL ID (*) \end{minipage} }    \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\multirow{3}{*}{ \hspace{1cm} } }    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \small DATE } & \small RESPONSIBLE & \small ROLE/SIGN (*) & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ \fbox{ \begin{minipage}{3cm} N.A. \end{minipage} } }    \\ \cline{3-7} 
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}                     & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ \small CODE }   & \small REV & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \small APPROVED } & \hspace{1cm} \small \pageref{LastPage} \ \\ \cline{3-7} 
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}                     & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ \tiny DOCUMENT ID }    & \tiny REVISION  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \tiny STATE } & \tiny NUMBER OF PAGES \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{center}

\end{document}

EDIT: I tried the solution in the answers but this is I get if DOC TYPE text is long (it goes off margin):


What do you expect for long document names? If you want line breaks, don't use a c column but a p column. The minipage trick you are already using could also help, but I don't like it, because usually it is not needed with p-columns. BTW: The table looks like someone used one of that table generators, that produce very ugly code.

Note that table is a float, so it makes no sense to wrap center around it. Use \centering inside the table env to center.

@cabohah For long document names, I expect them to be readable. Maybe expand the cell... thank you

as noted \begin{center} will not apply to teh table just add spurious vertical space at that position (not wheerthe table is placed) ald \begin{table}[] means do not allow the table anywhere, latex will warn about this. use \begin{table} not \begin{table}[]

It would help if you provided a usable example, this one stops with ! Package pdftex.def Error: File \apple.png' not found: using draft setting.`

why do you have so many multicolum over-riding your column settings? it makes the table markup weirdly complicated and you are losing all control over the column widths. You had p columns which would allow line breaking then you have over-ridden that with \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ Neque  so forcing a c column whch is always single line as wide as its content

@DavidCarlisle I have just inherited this setting from a former colleague, but I must apply edits since I noticed some issues. Also I edited my code in order to reproduce it without the png image.

Along with everything else, you want to use \textwidth instead of \paperwidth.

You were putting the name in a c column entry (via \multicolumn) so forcing that it is single line, this uses a p column as wide as the two columns it is spanning, plus the inter-column space. A few other fixes noted in comments.

Still a few warnings but you can fix thos as needed in your full document.
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  a4paper,
  top=1.5cm,
  bottom=1.5cm,
  left=1cm,
  right=1cm
}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[10pt]{moresize}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

% no\begin{center}
\begin{table}% no[]
    \caption{(*) If applicable}
    \vspace{1mm} % Adjust the height of the space between caption and tabular

% basing the column widths on \paperwidth is very weird it takes no account of the page margins
    
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.1\paperwidth}p{0.1\paperwidth}|p{0.1\paperwidth}p{0.1\paperwidth}|p{0.1\paperwidth}|p{0.1\paperwidth}p{0.12\paperwidth}|}
\hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{3}{*}{ \fbox{ \begin{minipage}{2cm} \ssmall DOC TYPE \end{minipage} } }} & \small Preparation & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \small DD/MM/YYYY } & \small DOC AUTHOR &  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ \begin{minipage}{3cm} \ssmall DOCUMENT NAME \end{minipage} }    \\ \cline{2-5}
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                  & \small Revision (*) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \small DD/MM/YYYY } & \small REVIEWER &  &
\multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr.22\paperwidth+2\tabcolsep}|}{ Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet } \\ \cline{2-7} 
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                  & \small Approval (*) & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \small DD/MM/YYYY } & \small APPROVER &  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ \begin{minipage}{3cm} \ssmall CDRL ID (*) \end{minipage} }    \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\multirow{3}{*}{ \hspace{1cm}
      % \includegraphics[scale=1]{apple.png}
  } }    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \small DATE } & \small RESPONSIBLE & \small ROLE/SIGN (*) & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ \fbox{ \begin{minipage}{3cm} N.A. \end{minipage} } }    \\ \cline{3-7} 
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}                     & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ \small CODE }   & \small REV & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \small APPROVED } & \hspace{1cm} \small \pageref{LastPage} \ \\ \cline{3-7} 
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}                     & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ \tiny DOCUMENT ID }    & \tiny REVISION  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \tiny STATE } & \tiny NUMBER OF PAGES \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
% no \end{center}

\chapter{Example Chapter}

\end{document}



I noticed that, if DOC TYPE is long, the text goes off margin. Please, check my post out. I have just edited it.

@tail well yes of course, you have arbitrarily allocated 0.1\paperwidth as the column width then used LOOOOOOOOOOOOONG as the doctype which is too long to fit  and not a real word so can not be hyphenated automatically you need a wider column, or smaller font or use LOOOOO\-OOOOOOOO\-NG or whatever to allow hyphenation. As I have already commented basing the column widths on fractions of \paperwidth is rather strange if not technically wrong.
